# Save TwitterAPI results to csv file

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I used premium API and codes below:

1st question:

## (1) worked (data in csv file) but #(2) didn't work (no data in csv file).

What makes the difference?
I need all items in #(2)

2nd question:
Final csv file had a blank line after each collected tweet. How can I delete a blank line.

---

```
import csv
csvFile=open('results.csv','w', encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter=csv.writer(csvFile)

consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

SEARCH_TERM = 'SEARCH_TERM'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'production'
```

############################(1) WORKING

```
for item in pager.get_iterator():
 if 'extended_tweet' in item:
  csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],item['extended_tweet']['full_text']])
 else:
  csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],item['text']])
```

############################(2) NOT WORKING WITHOUT ERROR MESSAGE

```
for item in pager.get_iterator():
 if 'extended_tweet' in item:
  csvWriter.writerow([item['id_str'], item['created_at'], item['user']['id'], item['user']['screen_name'], item['user']['followers_count'], item['retweet_count'], item['favorite_count'], item['extended_tweet']['full_text'], item['user']['location']])
 else:
  csvWriter.writerow([item['id_str'], item['created_at'], item['user']['id'], item['user']['screen_name'], item['user']['followers_count'], item['retweet_count'], item['favorite_count'], item['text'], item['user']['location']])
```

Comment: For your question:

 1. What is the error message?
 2.  When you open your csv file add `newline=''` like that:

 `open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: 
 ...`

Comment: I would suggest you to divide your question to 2 different threads next time

Comment: Looks like you might have `KeyError` (my guess). If so you need to account for that by checking if, for example, `id_string` exists in `item`. Alternatively, use `.get()` with the default value: `item['id_str']` becomes `item.get('id_str', 'default value')` and `item['user']['id']` becomes `item.get('user', {'id': 'default value'})`. Not a production ready approach, of course, but can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem.

item.get for question (1)
newline='' for question (2)